# Read compressed files without unzipping them in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gzip

I have (very large) comma separated files compressed in bz2 format. If I un-compressed them and I read with

```
    fileID = fopen('file.dat');
    X = textscan(fileID,'%d %d64 %s %f %d %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
    fclose(fileID);
```

everything is fine. But I would like to read them without uncompressing them, something like

```
    fileID = fopen('file.bz2');
    X = textscan(fileID,'%d %d64 %s %f %d %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
    fclose(fileID);
```

which, unfortunatley, returns an empty X. Any suggestions? Do I have to uncompressed them unavoidably via the system(' ... ') command ?

Comment: You're going to have to uncompress them. `textscan` has no way of parsing the raw bit stream from a compressed file.

Comment: yes, I am wondering wether other commands alternative to textscan allow for reading through zipped files.

Comment: you can uncompress the files in matlab I guess using `unzip` but you still need to use another function i.e. `textscan` to read it into matlab. What's wrong with unzipping?

Comment: I concur with the above. Also, I suggest that you compare manual decompression, matlab command for external decompression and finally internal decompression with matlab commands e.g. `unzip`. `unzip` is known to be very slow.

Comment: There is an unzip(zipfilename)command in matlab try using that

Comment: I would like to avoid compress and uncompress since there are a lot of files and it takes a while to do that (even from the terminal). I am realizing that unfortunately there is nothing similar to gzcat in matlab.

Comment: Wait. Does your zip contain multiple files or a single one? Because once it is read in MATLAB, it will have the uncompressed size, as, well, its uncompressed. If your bz2 has multiple files, this question makes sense, else its, pardon the adjective, nonsensical.

Comment: I didnt understand. The file .bz2 contains a single file, the compression factor is huge and I need to do that because I have thousands of these files and not enough storage for having them unzipped. So I loop over the files, I unzip the selected file, I read it with textscan, I do my operations in Matlab and then I am forced to zip the file for storage reason. Why my question is nonsensical? If I could read inside the file with an equivalent of gzcat I would save time, that's my only point.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the form of `textscan` that takes a string instead of a stream. Using the Matlab Java integration, you can leverage Java chained streams to decompress on the fly and read single lines, which can then be parsed:

```
% Build a stream chain that reads, decompresses and decodes the file into lines
fileStr = javaObject('java.io.FileInputStream', 'file.dat.gz');
inflatedStr = javaObject('java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream', fileStr);
charStr = javaObject('java.io.InputStreamReader', inflatedStr);
lines = javaObject('java.io.BufferedReader', charStr);

% If you know the size in advance you can preallocate the arrays instead
% of just stating the types to allow vcat to succeed
X = { int32([]), int64([]), {}, [], int32([]), [], [], int32([]) };
curL = lines.readLine();
while ischar(curL) % on EOF, readLine returns null, which becomes [] (type double)
    % Parse a single line from the file
    curX = textscan(curL,'%d %d64 %s %f %d %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
    % Append new line results 
    for iCol=1:length(X)
        X{iCol}(end+1) = curX{iCol};
    end
    curL = lines.readLine();
end
lines.close(); % Don't forget this or the file will remain open!
```

I'm not exactly vouching for the performance of this method, with all the array appending going on, but at least that is how you can read a GZ file on the fly in Matlab/Octave. Also:

- If you have a Java stream class that decompresses another format (try e.g. [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/)), you can read it the same way. You could read bzip2 or xz files.
- There are also classes to access *archives*, like zip files in the base Java distribution, or tar/RAR/7z and more in Apache Commons Compress. These classes usually have some way of finding files stored within the archive, allowing you to open an input stream to them *within the archive* and read in the same way as above.

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system I would use named pipes and do something like this:

```
system('mkfifo pipename');
system(['bzcat  file.bz2 >  pipename &']);
fileID = fopen('pipename', 'r');
X = textscan(fileID,'%d %d64 %s %f %d %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
fclose(fileID);
system('remove pipename');
```